# How to get three grayscale images from a RGB photo in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As per the title, I have a RGB photo and I'm trying to get three separate grayscale images, each one referring to a single channel (i.e., a grayscale image for R, G and B values).

From what I've read I should just make two channels invisible and simply export, but that's not working for me - I get the colored, three channels pic again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - You want just one channel separate from everthing else.

1. Go to the channels window, right click on the desired channel and click duplicate channel:
   [image]
2. On the duplicate window choose new file and you'll get a regular layer on a new file
   [image]